# phpseclib pear channel is broken

Tags: pear, phpseclib

1st/ http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/channel.xml contains URL to http://phpseclib.sourceforge.org which doesn't exist.

2nd/ packages are broken

```
$ tar tf Crypt_AES-0.3.6.tgz 
/Crypt_AES-0.3.6/Crypt/AES.php
package.xml
```

And package.xml

So pear expect Crypt_AES-0.3.6/AES.php which doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1):

You might try http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ instead.

Having just looked through the page it seems they have a git repository: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib

You can presumably use this to manually install the required package.

Also if I might suggest: report the problem to the developers there.

Comment: Reported here, because from http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/, "Get support" link point here...

Comment: I think stackoverflow is more intended for general support issues. ie. "how do I do this or that?". Not bug reports. Like with phpbb.com if you have general support questions you post in their discussion forums but they have a bug tracker for genuine bugs. Mozilla is the same way.

Comment: I agree with @neubert.

user3351288: I'm sure that for general support questions regarding the library this is a helpful place to get answers from other users of and sometimes developers of the library- I know it has been for me - However this particular problem should be reported to the developers somehow and there is no guarantee that they'll even see this question here.

Comment: It would appear that they have now fixed these links. I haven't tried using the package manager but just visually inspecting the xml file the link's domain no longer ends in .org but now .net which seems to work.